# jQuery - поиск элемента по ID

Tags: jquery, html

Имеется несколько элементов. У каждого ID уникален. То есть, даже случайный.
То есть:

```
<a id="132">
<a id="13242">
<a id="1234">
<a id="1222">
<a id="434232">
<a id="132424">
```

Вот как мне найти один из этих элементов, если я заведомой знаю его ID?
Чтоб было более понятно, что я хочу:
ниже, есть кнопка, которая удаляет один из вышеуказанных элементов.
Как это можно реализовать?

```
<a href="#" class="RemoveElement" removeID="132">Удалить элемент</a>

$(function() {
        $(".RemoveElement").click(function (event) {
            alert($(this).attr("removeID"));
            $("div.items > ")
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В теле `...click(function(event) {`

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("removeID")).hide();
// или:
$("a[removeID='" + $(this).attr("removeID") + "']").hide();
```

Можно использовать `fadeOut(1000); //время в мс`. Чтобы вернуть обратно, делаем `show();`, либо `fadeIn(1000);`

PS Если не ошибаюсь, в качестве id не рекомендуется использовать цифры на начале. То есть мб следует заменить все id на `id="i132"` такой вид.

Comment: прошу прощения, за небольшую дезинформация в вопросе. А если у меня id у всех одинаковый, а есть дополнительный параметр removeID
    <a id="1" removeID>    
Не спрашивайте, зачем так делал. Там целая история. :)

Comment: Попробуйте вторую строчку, я обновил ответ.

Comment: отлично. Спасибо, работает.
а можно сделать как - то так, чтобы элемент не прятался, а удалялся?

Comment: можно.
$("a[removeID='" + $(this).attr("removeID") + "']").remove(); но учтите что это удаление только с вашего экрана а не из базы. для удаления из базы вам нужно аяксом хотя бы запрос послать в скрипт.